# How to set output resistance of an amplifier to be 50k

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, circuit-design, bjt, resistance

I need to build an amplifier using BJTs / resistors / capacitors.

It should have specific parameters (up to 5% error), and I’ve reached them all except for the output resistance.

The parameters are as following:

- Voltage gain: 35 dB
- BW: 6 kHz - 600 kHz
- Bode gain slopes:

  - +40 dB/dec before intermediate freq.
  - -20dB/dec afterwards.
- Input resistance: 57 Ω
- Output resistance: 50 kΩ  ( 2 decades before and after intermediary freqeuency.)

I built the amplifier using CB as follows:

[image]

But I didn’t manage to get the right output resistance. I tried to use another CC/CE at the output.

But I wasn’t able to give it 50k output resistance and work at DC. 
(I can use only +-5 V power supplies, so the currents I get are too low.)

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to do it using the amplifier I already built, or do I need to start from scratch?

Comment: What *is* the output impedance you can reach?

Comment: Currently it’s 2 mega at low freq. and it goes down as the freq. rises and reaches constant 48.8k at high freq. after both capacitors are shortened. 
Because i get 50k || 2 mega

Answer (score 1):

I'm ignoring C3, R3 and R (2 Mohm) because they are largely unrequired.

In a common emitter/base configuration, it is the collector resistor (\$R_C\$) that sets the output impedance. In your circuit it has a value of 100 kohm and this is in parallel with the collector (acting as a constant current source) so, if the BJT were ideal, your output impedance would be 100 kohm. Bingo!

A real BJT might have a non-infinite output impedance of many tens of kohm and that, in parallel with \$R_C\$ dictates the true output impedance. However you are operating as a common base so you should definitely place a capacitor decoupler across \$R_{B2}\$ to ensure that signal feedback to the base (via the BJT's "miller" capacitor) does not ruin HF performance.

It can be quite tricky to achieve but, once you have a stable impedance at the collector, if it's below 50 kohm then you may need to pad it up to 50 kohm with a series resistor in your output line.